# How do I get the position of a component in UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I want to add a "min" label next to a component in UIPickerView. To determine the x-coordinate, I need to know the component's x-coordinate so that I can set it up in such a way that it adjusts according to different screen devices.

Comment: Please provide some more details for better understand (like images).

Answer (score 1):

You can test if your item is last in `func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?` and add min text to "component".

Egzample:

```
// MARK: - Properties

private var dataSource: [PickerViewItem] = [...]

// MARK: - UIPickerViewDataSource

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if (row == self.dataSource.count - 1) {
        return "min: " + self.dataSource[row].description
    }
    return self.dataSource[row].description
}
```

If you want have different font or text size, you can use `func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString?` method to format your string.